# Disobeying recommended pad size of 0603 LED

Tags: led, pcb, surface-mount, pad, reflow

I need to pack a cluster of 0603 LEDs (https://docs.rs-online.com/c349/0900766b81180479.pdf) as close together as possible on a PCB. The datasheet recommends a pad-to-pad width of 2.3mm.

As the board will be populated via a pick and place machine and reflow soldered, can I reduce the pad-to-pad distance to the width of the component (1.6mm)?

Why does the datasheet recommend a larger pad footprint, is this to aid in hand soldering?

What risks do I incur by reducing the pad footprint?

Comment: This is a question for your assembly house. They'll know their own processes best, and be able to tell you if their machines can handle a differently-sized footprint. Most likely they can handle at least a somewhat-shrunken pad size with the trade-off being an increased scrap rate.

Comment: Why not use 0402 if you need to fit them closer together?

Comment: @MattS, so this is only an issue of manufacturability then?

Comment: I agree with Matt S. I'm afraid you'll have to talk to your assembly house. They can tell you how closely you can space the LEDs and what pad size will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reducing the pad spacing to 1.6 and reducing the pad length to, say 0.4mm would probably work but it would give you no room for error on land overhang and solder fillet inspectability, though the castellation might be sufficient.  Your assembly house will not like it since if they have AOI it might throw a fit, though if you specifically waive the inspection requirements for those parts they may allow it.  As Matt S said, you will probably end up with more boards scrapped or needing rework.  Getting a few test boards might be a prudent course of action.